# Modifying git repository root config

Tags: git

I'm adding a git commit template to help standardise our commit notes.

I have added the template and modified the local `.git/config' file to include the template, but this only applies to this specific clone.

Is there a way of modifying `.git/config` to include a value for `commit.template` within the Git Repository root, so that when anyone clones the repository they have the settings available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enforce configuration settings in cloned repositories.

What you *can* do is package up your templates and hook script as part of the repository, and then include some sort of "setup" script that will copy them into all of the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was able to find was modifying the systemwide `.gitconfig` file to include a path for `commit.template` relative to the repository.

When a fresh clone is made

While the systemwide `.gitconfig` file has the lowest priority, as described in [Git Configuration](https://foo.cs.ucsb.edu/56wiki/index.php/Git_Guide#Git_Configuration), if the local or global configuration file is not modified it will be applied across all repositories on the system.